# Is it possible to source a batch file in windows cmd like you can in unix?

Tags: windows, batch-file, call

I'm a unix guy but I have to write a system in windows, and I'm trying to write a script to move some files around. I'm trying to have the parent batch file CALL a child batch file which contains:

```
set REPORTFILE=c:\report.txt
```

and then I want the parent to be able to use the %REPORTFILE% variable. Apparently the CALL command creates a new context.
In unix, you just source the script, is that possible in windows?

Comment: now I'm thinking I can do some trick like in unix  REPORTFILE='cat filewithname.txt'. (make believe those are backticks)  Is there an equivalent of that in windows?

Comment: ahhhh... is this it? set /p REPORTFILE= < tmpFile

Comment: CALL does not create a new context unless the called script/routine issues SETLOCAL. You should show a complete example (master and child) that you think is failing. I suspect you may be calling and setting the value within parentheses which would require delayed expansion.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

if I understand...this seems to work for me in Vista:

caller.bat

```
echo this is the caller
echo initial value is: %reportfile%
call setter.bat
echo value is: %reportfile%
```

setter.bat

```
echo this is the value setter
set reportfile=c:\report.txt
```

C:\temp>caller

> C:\temp>echo this is the caller
> `this is the caller`
> C:\temp>echo initial value is:
> `initial value is:`
> C:\temp>call setter.bat
>
> > C:\temp>echo this is the value setter
> > `this is the value setter`
> > C:\temp>set reportfile=c:\report.txt
>
> C:\temp>echo value is: c:\report.txt
> `value is: c:\report.txt`

updated to use goto instead of parens:

```
if not exist file.txt goto doit
goto notfound
:doit 
echo this is the caller 
echo initial value is: %reportfile% 
call setter.bat
echo value is: %reportfile%
goto end
:notfound
 echo file found 
:end
```

Comment: yeah that doesn't work for me in XP. If you run that script and then do set reportfile   what do you get? I found that the variable was set in my calling context, but not in the script.

Comment: reportfile=c:\report.txt
...after "set reportfile" for me

Comment: I see your case working, mine was a bit more complex, I changed yours to add the parens and then it started failing, change your caller.bat to this:  if not exist file.txt (
echo this is the caller
echo initial value is: %reportfile%
call setter.bat
echo value is: %reportfile%
) else ( echo file found
)

Comment: i think the problem is the parens () ...i removed and used goto, and :labels and it worked...added above so code would be more readable

Comment: yeah, I did the same thing and got it to work that way, but the parens should or should not create a new context, it appears to do it half way. makes no sense. Windows needs more unix.